# Execution of INSERT with format() raises an error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Trying to execute the following:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (idinstrum, varname, enable, subaddr, id_device, id_synchronization_request, pupdate) VALUES (4, %s, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);', 'test');
  END
$$;
```

I get this error:

> ```
> [42703] ERROR: column "test" does not exist
>  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

What's wrong with my DDL?

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL for that? That is not needed for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder `%s` will put the value from the parameter "as is" into the string. But you want the parameter to be treated as a literal (constant).

You need to use the placeholder `%L` for that:

```
format('.... (4, %L, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764)', 'test')
```

For an `execute` you also don't need to terminate the statement with a `;`

Comment: You don't need the semicolon at the *end* of the command string passed to `EXECUTE`. It's required between multiple statements, though. Just like in the body of an SQL functions: the semicolon after the *last* command is noise. Also, it's preferable for *values* to be passed in with a `USING` clause. Concatenating them as string literals is more expensive and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

@Olaf and @a_horse explained your problem. The solution is:

Either

```
EXECUTE format($$
    INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (idinstrum, varname, enable, subaddr, id_device, id_synchronization_request, pupdate) VALUES
    (4, %L, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);
    $$', 'test'
);
```

Or `execute` without `format`

```
EXECUTE $$
    INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (idinstrum, varname, enable, subaddr, id_device, id_synchronization_request, pupdate)
    VALUES (4, $1, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);
    $$ using 'test';
```

Comment: `USING` for *values* is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with my DDL?

The function [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) outputs a string according to some `printf` style format string. Your string

```
format('INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (...) VALUES (4, %s, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);', 'test')
```

becomes

```
INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (...) VALUES (4, test, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);
```

which is an insert statement trying to insert the value of column `test` for the second value.

---

To insert `test` as a string, you may try a [Dollar-quoted String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING), e.g.

```
format('INSERT INTO public."EWcfgvars" (...) VALUES (4, %s, 1, 0, 122, 1, 1464022764);', $$'test'$$)
```

Comment: Using `%L` to let Postgres handle the correct literal format is much better